# convention for marking LaTeX in programming comments?

Tags: comments

Is there a convention for marking the beginning of LaTeX-based material placed inside the comments of (say) a C++ or Python program? Or does one simply jump into LaTeX syntax?

Comment: `\begin{latex}` :-)

Comment: In python, you can use [sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org) for documentation, which uses `.. math::` for equations by default.

Answer (score 3):

In [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) the [convention](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/formulas.html) is to explain TeX environments with \f.

As doxygen documentation goes in comments, you might call this convention for comments, though it is more convention for in-code documentation.